# error while running code in xcode Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

i wrote code in visual c++ which works perfect on windows. but when i tried to run it in xcode mac it gives me following various errors. one of them is given below:

Undefined symbols for `architecture x86_64`:

```
"cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)", referenced from:

preprocessImage(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&) in main.o

readingProcssingImages(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__1::allocator<cv::Mat> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__1::allocator<cv::Mat> > > >&) in main.o

ErrorSensitivityOneToOne1D(std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__1::allocator<cv::Mat> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__1::allocator<cv::Mat> > > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__1::allocator<cv::Mat> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__1::allocator<cv::Mat> > > > > >&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__1::allocator<cv::Mat> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__1::allocator<cv::Mat> > > >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__1::allocator<cv::Mat> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__1::allocator<cv::Mat> > > >&, std::__1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__1::allocator<cv::Mat> >&) in main.o

callToShowImages(std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__1::allocator<cv::Mat> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__1::allocator<cv::Mat> > > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__1::allocator<cv::Mat> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__1::allocator<cv::Mat> > > > > >&) in main.o
```

can any body guide me in this regards. thanks

Comment: Looks like you aren't linking in the OpenCV library?

Comment: I think you are right, let me check,,

Comment: how to link OpenCV lib using xcode?